# NestJs Pipe vs filter

Tags: nestjs

I was going through the NestJs Docs. And there's this image.

https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes

[image: filter vs pipe diagram nestJs]

Filters are more oriented towards Client-Side and pipes are towards Controllers. To me both seems similar.

**What are the differences between Pipe and filter with their respective common use-cases ?**

Comment: I know that there are exception Filters. It it their only type ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Pipes](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes) are meant to consuming incoming data from the request, be it url or query parameters, or a request body, and do some validations and/or transformations on them to ensure they are the shape your server expects them to be. Nest has some built in utilities like the [ValidationPipe](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation) to help with this.

[Filters (AKA Exception Filters)](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters) on the other hand are meant for catching errors that happened during the execution of a request and handling it, sending the error back to the client in a nice format, taking care of sending back the proper error codes, and any other error handling logic you have (like possibly sending to a monitoring service). Nest has a built in ExceptionFilter that manages this nicely, but you can always create your own to handle the logic differently.

Comment: PIPES validate data. If data is invalidated ,it returns error. Filter - only catches error, and sends back Formatted Error response